# How to get the HTML Table row records which is added dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

> I want to get the row records, which is added dynamically. I am getting an output if I add the row using html.

At beginning there will be no records in table. this is my code.

**HTML Code**

```
<table class="table table-hover " id="queryTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Field Name</th>
           <th>Values</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Table with empty row At beginning]
When user click **ADD Button**It will be added rows using jquery successfully

[image: After Added rows by user clicking the ADD Button]
**JQUERY Code**

```
$('#queryTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td class="FieldNameID">' + selectedField + '</td><td class="OperatorID"> IN(' + $("#txtFilterValue").val() + ')</td></tr>');
```

> Upto this it's working fine. Now, When user clicks on any row, I want to select the row and show it in alert box, which is added dynamcally.

Comment: You dont need `:last-child`

Comment: @Hemal that is not the problem now, I got the output to add the rows in table dynamically. Now I want to get the row records using jquery when user click any rows after it added

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/70w9t588/5/)

The elements which are added dynamically, you have to bind an event this way.

```
$(document).on("click",'#queryTable tbody tr',function(){
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Show only `td` values

```
 $(document).on("click",'#queryTable tbody tr',function(){
   var tr=$(this);
   var firsttd=tr.find("td:first").text();
   var secondtd=tr.find("td:last").text(); //BECAUSE YOU HAVE ONLY 2 TDs
   alert(firsttd + ' ' + secondtd);
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/70w9t588/6/)

Comment: but it's displaying all the HTML Elements. I wants to alert only those two td values

Comment: Select as answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Use a function which has a callback function. Like bellow:

```
function AddNewRow(selectedField,callback){
   var $newRow=$('<tr><td class="FieldNameID">' + selectedField + '</td><td class="OperatorID"> IN(' + $("#txtFilterValue").val() + ')</td></tr>');
   $('#queryTable > tbody:last-child').append($newRow);
   callback($newRow);
}
```

How it works:

```
$(document).on("click",'#selector',function(){
 var selectedField='some value';
  AddNewRow(selectedField,function($tr){
    // $tr is your new Added Tr.
    // Code will goes here
  });
});
```